# Determining the image of a function in two dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $f(x, y) = e^x (\cos y, \sin y)^T$. Determine the image of $f$, i.e., $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I trired to visualize it with a software and I got this solution, which I can't really understand.

[image]

This is my attempt:

Determine the image of $f$, i.e., $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

To find the image of $f$, which is $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$, we substitute $x$ and $y$ with arbitrary real numbers and examine the resulting vectors.

Let $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be an arbitrary vector. We plug in $x = a$ and $y = b$ into the function $f$:

$f(a, b) = e^a(\cos b, \sin b)^t$

Since $e^a$ is always positive, we obtain the vector $f(a, b)$ as:

$f(a, b) = e^a(\cos b, \sin b)^t = e^a\cos b \cdot (1, 0)^t + e^a\sin b \cdot (0, 1)^t$

Note that $(1, 0)^t$ represents the unit vector in the direction of the x-axis, and $(0, 1)^t$ represents the unit vector in the direction of the y-axis. Thus, we can express $f(a, b)$ as a linear combination of the vectors $(1, 0)^t$ and $(0, 1)^t$ with coefficients $e^a\cos b$ and $e^a\sin b$, respectively.

Therefore, we can characterize the image of $f$ as:

$f(\mathbb{R}^2) = \{e^a\cos b \cdot (1, 0)^t + e^a\sin b \cdot (0, 1)^t : a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$

The image of $f$ consists of all linear combinations of the unit vectors $(1, 0)^t$ and $(0, 1)^t$, multiplied by the corresponding scalars $e^a\cos b$ and $e^a\sin b$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: The image is equal $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$

Comment: Hint : $f(z) = e^z$ on the complex plane.